# How I manupulate these files in terminal at the same time

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, loopback

I have 139 different tab-delimited `.txt` files. I want to add a column to each file containing the name of that `.txt` file and finally attached all .txt files in one file; Let's say I have `A.txt`, `B.txt`, `C.txt` files, and in each of these files I have such columns

```
chrM    10458   C   T
chrM    13960   C   T
chrM    14173   T   C
chr1    920552  G   A
```

I need something like

```
A   chrM    10458   C   T
A   chrM    13960   C   T
A   chrM    14173   T   C
A   chr1    920552  G   A
B   chr1    1350208 G   A
B   chr1    1447367 T   G
B   chr1    1909310 G   A
B   chr1    2172675 G   C
C   chr1    2846623 C   T
C   chr1    3057894 G   A
C   chr1    3096688 G   C
C   chr1    3154525 G   A
```

Can you help me in doing that please?

Thank you

Comment: are the files tab-delimited? and if space-delimited? do you need to keep the amount of spaces?

Comment: Thank you, they are tab-delimited and the extra column has space as the other columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk` and `FILENAME` variable.
To strip off the extension, you can use the `gsub` function:

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{gsub(/.txt$/,"",FILENAME); print FILENAME,$0}' *.txt
```

Add `> MERGE.txt` to the end to put the result in a new text file.

Comment: Careful about adding `> MERGE.txt`, as the redirection takes place before the `*` expansion, so the `awk ... *.txt` will include `MERGE.txt` in its processing. You should probably output to `MERGE.tmp` and then `mv MERGE.tmp MERGE.txt`

Comment: you're right, although I don't think it will affect the output as MERGE.txt will be empty when `awk` reads it.

Comment: Not necessarily, it won't.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a trick, but you could search for anything (the dot) in all files with `grep`. That will add the name of the file at the beginning of each line, to let you know where the match ocurred. The, with `sed` you substitute part of the prefixed filename (".txt:" with a space):

```
grep . *.txt | sed 's/.txt:/ /g'
```

It wastes quite a few cpu cycles, but for a one-timer, it's ok, it will get the job done.

Comment: nice idea :-) you should replace `.txt` with tab instead of space.

Comment: For me it is impossible to learn these, too complicated :(

Comment: @Angel, run the first part of the pipeline with just a couple of files, so you can see what it's producing (for example `grep . aa.txt bb.txt`). Then apply the `sed` to that sample output and see if you can work out what it's doing. If you can't, ask Eduardo to explain their answer in more detail for you.

Comment: Eduardo, your solution will fail if `*.txt` expands to only one file. You might want to use `grep -h ...` to force the presence of the filename.

Comment: Well, the OP explicitely stated there were 139 of them. I'm pretty new here and I do try to make room for similar questions, but I thought that, in this case, all of them would involve multiple files. If I had added the -h I'm pretty sure somebody would've pointed out that it was unnecessary... Still good point.

Comment: @roaima , Sorry the size of tmp file is different with .txt file; I mean when directly I have MERGE.txt, the size of file is not the same when I am getting MERGE.tmp then mv to .txt; How it is possible?

Comment: @Angel because the MERGE.txt file with partial results is being included in the set of files to be processed.